# Trying to Understand an Implementation of Hash#merge with Procs

Tags: ruby, hash, merge

trying to understand this problem here. I am creating my own verison of the hash#merge called hash#my_merge that can take in a proc. I'm trying to understand what does do:

```
self.each do |k,v|
  newhash[k]=hash[k] ? prc.call(k,v,hash[k]): v
end
```

Its look like a ternary operation but newhash[k]=hash[k] isn't a true/false statement? The prompt and the rest of the question is as follows:

```
class Hash
# Hash#merge takes a proc that accepts three arguments: a key and the two
# corresponding values in the hashes being merged. Hash#merge then sets that
# key to the return value of the proc in a new hash. If no proc is given,
# Hash#merge simply merges the two hashes.
#
# Write a method with the functionality of Hash#merge. Your Hash#my_merge 
method
# should optionally take a proc as an argument and return a new hash. If a 
proc
# is not given, your method should provide default merging behavior. Do not 
use
# Hash#merge in your method.

  def my_merge(hash, &prc)
    prc ||=Proc.new{|k,oldval,newval|}
    newhash=Hash.new

    self.each do |k,v|
      newhash[k]=hash[k] ? prc.call(k,v,hash[k]): v
    end

    hash.each do |k,v|
      newhash[k]=v if newhash[k].nil?
    end
    newhash
  end
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line your misunderstanding is a ternary, but the order of operations aren't what you're expecting. When Ruby sees:

```
newhash[k]=hash[k] ? prc.call(k,v,hash[k]): v
```

it views it as

```
newhash[k]= (hash[k] ? prc.call(k,v,hash[k]): v)
```

So, if `hash[k]` is a truth-y value, call the proc and assign the result to `newhash[k]`; otherwise, assign `v` to `newhash[k]`.

You can see that this is how Ruby views this line by looking at the [Operator Precedence](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html) file, which has (among a bunch of other operators):

> ?, :
>
> modifier-rescue
>
> =, +=, -=, etc.

So the ternary is higher precedence than the assignment operators.

---

It's also worth noting that `newhash[k] = hash[k]` is, in Ruby, a true/false statement, since assignment returns what was assigned:

```
a = 1 # => 1
a = nil # => nil
```

and everything except for `false` and `nil` in Ruby are seen as a truth-y value, you can do stuff like:

```
if a = 2
  puts "truthy"
end
# outputs 'truthy'
```

and

```
if a = nil
  puts "truthy"
end
# outputs nothing
```

and with proper parenthesizing, you can use it in a ternary:

```
(a = 1) ? 'truthy' : 'falsey' # => 'truthy'
(a = nil) ? 'truthy' : 'falsey' # => 'falsey'
```

Though, this can be confusing (usually in a conditional you'd see `==` not `=`, and in fact my Ruby gives me a warning that I'm using the `=` instead of `==` in a conditional); but it can be done

Answer (score 3):

While your core problem is one of [operator precedence](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html) when using a ternary in that fashion, the real issue is an over-complication of the actual solution.

If you're just getting started with Ruby do your best to avoid things like ternary statements to keep your code as simple and obvious as possible. For example, what does the following do:

```
a = nil

a = true ? :yes : :no
```

If you think the answer is "`a` is assigned `:yes`" then you're reading it correctly. If you think "`a` is assigned `true`" then you're forgetting that the ternary `?` has a higher precedence than `=` for assignment so it happens first.

The same wouldn't be true if you looked at it this way:

```
if (a = true)
  :yes
else
  :no
end
```

Or the alternative interpretation laid clear:

```
a =
  if (true)
    :yes
  else
    :no
  end
```

Where the outcome of those two is immediately apparent with even a basic understanding of programming. This can also be handy if it's really late at night and you're trying to fix a bug and you can't figure out your own code because you've made it too convoluted.

That being said, a reworked solution looks like this:

```
class Hash
  def my_merge(hash)
    # Figure out all the keys that might show up in this merge in advance.
    keys = (self.keys + hash.keys).uniq
    newhash = { }

    # Try all possible keys and evaluate what the result should be
    keys.each do |k|
      newhash[k] =
        if (block_given?)
          yield(k, self[k], hash[k])
        elsif (self.has_key?(k))
          self[k]
        else
          hash[k]
        end
    end

    newhash
  end
end
```

You can leverage the way `if` actually returns values in Ruby to make short work of this problem and keep the inner logic pretty clear.

One thing to note is when you use `Hash.new` you probably mean `{ }` instead. The formal declaration is reserved for things like `Hash.new(0)` or `Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [ ] }` where the first sets a static default and the second is a computed default. If you're not setting a default, don't use the explicit initializer. It just adds noise.

You can also make better use of the built-in features of Ruby that allow significantly minimizing the amount of temporary variables you need, plus the amount of work you actually have to do to effect a transform like this. For example, a little tidying up and you get this:

```
class Hash
  def my_merge(hash)
    (self.keys + hash.keys).uniq.map do |k|
      [
        k,
        if (block_given?)
          yield(k, self[k], hash[k])
        elsif (self.has_key?(k))
          self[k]
        else
          hash[k]
        end
      ]
    end.to_h
  end
end
```

That's pretty lean and the biggest chunk of code there is your `merge` implmentation, as it should be, not all the set-up and clean-up code.